# Did this method 'method' throw this error message?

Tags: ruby, error-handling

The ruby code

```
class Word < Array
   def g
      puts "JJ"
   end
end

w = Word.new([4, 6])
puts Word.method(:g)
```

produces the following error:

```
main.rb:9:in `method': undefined method `g' for class `#<Class:Word>' (NameError)
        from main.rb:9:in `<main>'
```

because `g` is an instance method for `Word`, not its class method.

It looks like it is the method `method` that in fact threw this error message. I wouldn't be able to explain how such an error message could be produced if that were not the case.

Is it in fact the method method that threw this error message?

Here, we are passing the symbol `:g` to the method `Word.method`, and waiting for its execution. The ruby interpreter cannot know beforehand that it's gonna be an error, only when the method `method` checks for the existence of a function with a name similar to the symbol `:g` can it (the method) decide that an error exists. The console/interpreter cannot know about the error beforehand.

Comment: Before keep posting questions one after another, do you have any idea of accepting and/or communicating with any of the answers to your previous questions?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. The description:

```
in `method'
```

in the error message means exactly that.

Comment: So the method "method" threw the error message via exceptions?

Comment: I said **yes**.